# Email Delayed - Google Apps

Tags: email, gmail, delay

I have google app for sending email on behalf of my domain. It’s a free google app account where I have 50 users in it.

The problem is that the users are having issue receiving the emails, emails get delayed sometime we don’t receive the email at all.

I have checked the spam folder no trace of any emails.

Because of this we miss most of our important emails. So I there a way to know why the emails get delayed or not received or how can I contact google(gmail) in this regards for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using the same service for a looooong time and no problems whatsoever.
I would bet the problem is either on your registrar or hosting.

Login to your registrar, and check the nameservers(!!!) and dns records.